# Why does this non-circular inheritance in Python trigger an import error?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, module, importerror

**EDIT:** Turns out the inheritance is circular. Read on!

I am using Python 3.6. I tried to produce a minimal code sample to debug an import error I was having in a code project which was caused by the way I have set up inheritance. I suspect that I have done something wrong, but I don't understand what principle of coding I have violated.

The file structure looks like this:

```
temp
 |-- __init__.py
 |-- superclass_file.py
 |-- subclass_file.py 
 |-- tests
      |-- __init__.py
      |-- test_subclass_file.py
```

These are the contents of the Python scripts:

```
# temp/__init__.py

from .subclass_file import *
from .superclass_file import *
```

```
# temp/superclass_file.py

class Parent:

    def __init__(self):
        print('I exist.')
```

```
# temp/subclass_file.py

from temp import Parent


class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('And I exist because of it.')

    def print_something(self):
        print('Yes, I\'m here.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Child()
```

```
# temp/tests/__init__.py

from .test_subclass_file import *
```

```
# temp/tests/test_subclass_file.py

from unittest import TestCase

from temp import Child


class TestChild(TestCase):

    def check_inheritance(self):
        c = Child()

        c.print_something()
```

When I run `check_inheritance()`, it fails and throws this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.6 ~/temp/subclass_file.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/temp/subclass_file.py", line 1, in <module>
    from temp import Parent
  File "~/temp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .subclass_file import *
  File "~/temp/subclass_file.py", line 1, in <module>
    from temp import Parent
ImportError: cannot import name 'Parent'
```

I obtain a similar error when I run the `main()` method in `subclass_file.py`.

*However*, the error disappears completely when I change the import of `Parent` in `subclass_file.py` from `from temp import Parent` to `from temp.superclass_file import Parent`.

Why does this happen? Why can't I use the same import signature I would use anywhere else—`from temp import Parent`—in the case of inheritance? Have I configured the `__init__.py` file incorrectly?

Comment: It is circular. `temp.subclass_file` imports `temp`, which has to import `.subclass_file`, which has to import `temp`, which imports `.subclass_file`, which imports ....

Comment: I thought naïvely that the imports would be cleared up by the Python interpreter. Thanks, @chepner. My question now is which way is better from the perspective of cleanliness of code. I would prefer an import like `from x import y` rather than `from z.x import y`. Not sure which is better in the long run, though.

Comment: I would import `Parent` directly from `superclass_file`, rather than through the "public" interface.

Comment: I think I'll do that for safety's sake. Should I continue to expose `Parent` and `Child` like I have in `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are importing `subclass_file.py` before `superclass_file.py`.

So when you try to do `from temp import Parent`, because `subclass_file.py` was imported before, it doesn't know what `Parent` is. Furthermore, you may create a circular import issue.

The best way should be to use `from temp.superclass_file import Parent`

If you really want / need to use the other way, then you must import `superclass_file.py` before `subclass_file.py`